# Java: Initializing a public static field in superclass that needs a different value in every subclass instance

Tags: java, static, initialization, subclass, final

Good evening,

I am developing a set of Java classes so that a container class `Box` contains a `List` of a contained class `Widget`. A `Widget` needs to be able to specify relationships with other `Widgets`. I figured a good way to do this would be to do something like this:

```
public abstract class Widget {
    public static class WidgetID {
        // implementation stolen from Google's GWT
        private static int nextHashCode;
        private final int index;

        public WidgetID() {
            index = ++nextHashCode;
        }

        public final int hashCode() {
            return index;
        }
    }

    public abstract WidgetID getWidgetID();

}
```

so sublcasses of `Widget` could:

```
public class BlueWidget extends Widget {
    public static final WidgetID WIDGETID = new WidgetID();

    @Override
    public WidgetID getWidgetID() {
        return WIDGETID;
    }
}
```

Now, `BlueWidget` can do `getBox().addWidgetRelationship(RelationshipTypes.SomeType, RedWidget.WIDGETID`, and `Box` can iterate through it's list comparing the second parameter to `iter.next().getWidgetID()`.

Now, all this works great so far. What I'm trying to do is keep from having to declare the `public static final WidgetID WIDGETID` in all the subclasses and implement it instead in the parent `Widget` class. The problem is, if I move that line of code into `Widget` (along with the implementation of `getWidgetID()`), then every instance of a subclass of `Widget` appears to get the same `static final WidgetID` for their `Subclassname.WIDGETID`. However, making it non-static means I can no longer even call `Subclassname.WIDGETID`.

So: how do I create a static `WidgetID` in the parent `Widget` class while ensuring it is different for every instance of `Widget` and subclasses of `Widget`? Or am I using the wrong tool for the job here?

Thanks!

[Edit] I would prefer not to require users of the library to call `super()` in all their sub-`Widget` constructors.

Comment: Is the WidgetID supposed to identify an instance of Widget, or a subclass of Widgets? That is, do you need to distinguish RedWidgets?

Comment: No; it is assumed that (actually, written so that) `Box` will only contain a single instance of each subclass of `Widget`. Perhaps I should have called it `ExclusiveBox`. :) `WidgetID` will identify only a subclass of `Widget`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If every subclass has a different value, the variable isn't a member of the superclass.

In other words, yes, each subclass should declare its own WIDGETID; you cannot consolidate those members of various classes as a single member in a superclass.

Comment: Marked as the correct answer since it answers the question proposed, although other answers provided useful ideas.

Answer (score 5):

Since it seems like the idea is that the WidgetID be unique for each specific subclass, why don't you just identify them by their class instead?

So where you are doing `getBox().addWidgetRelationship(RelationshipTypes.SomeType, RedWidget.WIDGETID)` you could do `getBox().addWidgetRelationship(RelationshipTypes.SomeType, RedWidget.class)` instead.

Comment: I actually like this method; if Google Web Toolkit supports this, it sounds ideal. Can you specify that a method should only accept `Class` objects that come from `Widget` or its subclasses? E.g., so that one couldn't pass in `someRandomObject.class`?

Comment: Binary: Yes, declare the parameter as `Class<? extends Widget>`

Answer (score 0):

Why not just declare an abstract method within Widget such as:

```
protected abstract WidgetID getWidgetID();
```

This way, each subclass must implement the method and return its own value. You can still declare WidgetID to be static within the subclasses, but the above instance method to return the 'unique' value.

Comment: With that interface, you can only refer to a widget if you already have an instance of that widget. In his example, knowing the class was enough.

Comment: This functionality (Jason's original answer) is how things currently work in my question. Perhaps that is a sign. :)